# Mysql5.5 win10 1067

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-10, mysql-5.5

```
>D:\cs_app\mysql\mysql-5.5.40-winx64\bin>mysqld --console
>170415 16:33:05 [Warning] Can't create test file D:\cs_app\mysql\mysql-5.5.40-winx64\data\??.lower-test
>170415 16:33:05 [Warning] Can't create test file D:\cs_app\mysql\mysql-5.5.40-winx64\data\??.lower-test
>170415 16:33:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>170415 16:33:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>170415 16:33:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>170415 16:33:05 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>170415 16:33:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>170415 16:33:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>170415 16:33:05 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>170415 16:33:05  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>170415 16:33:06 InnoDB: 5.5.40 started; log sequence number 1595675
>170415 16:33:06 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
>170415 16:33:06 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
>170415 16:33:06 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
>170415 16:33:06 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file 'D:\cs_app\mysql\mysql-5.5.40-winx64\data\??.pid' (Errcode: 22)
>170415 16:33:06 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Invalid argument


my.ini
[mysqld]
basedir=D:\\cs_app\\mysql\\mysql-5.5.40-winx64
datadir=D:\\cs_app\\mysql\\mysql-5.5.40-winx64\\data
character_set_server=utf8
[client]  
character_set_server=utf8
[WinMySQLAdmin]  
Server=D:\\cs_app\\mysql\\mysql-5.5.40-winx64\\bin\\mysqld.exe  
user=root
```

When I code `net start mysql` it gives me `1067`.

Comment: I tried to improve the question and add relevant tags, but this is not my regular IT domain.  Anyone is welcome to make improvements to clarify this question.

Comment: `mysqld: Can't create/write to file 'D:\cs_app\mysql\mysql-5.5.40-winx64\data\??.pid' (Errcode: 22)` -- this should be an important clue.. does the directory exists? is it writable? also what is the user that runs the service? perhaps trying in ServerFault will give better answer..

Comment: i try to use MySQL5.5 on Windows10, but after i setup mysql,  i cant strat mysql service, everytime i code net start mysql in cmd, it just give me error 1067 , that is my sql console,and my.ini is config file,   i stuck here for all day, very sad ;(

Comment: i`m sure that directory is exists,and run this service in cmd with administrator rights, is it writable?  maybe, check it now  happy~~~

Comment: thank u my friend, that`s the problem, really appreciate it